# Confusion with eigenvalues, needs clarification

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> **Problem** 3 on page 882 [here](https://noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/mat-1.1020/materiaali/Mat-1_1020_juhani_pitkaranta__tkk_n_laaja_matematiikka_ii__2007_.pdf?state:CourseAdditionalMaterial=BrO0ABXcgAAAAAgAAGWVkaXRVc2VyV2FudHNUb0NoYW5nZUZpbGVzcgARamF2YS5sYW5nLkJvb2xlYW7NIHKA1Zz67gIAAVoABXZhbHVleHAAdxMAABBlZGl0RGlhbG9nSGlkZGVuc3EAfgAAAQ%3D%3D), translated:
>
> The matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 & -1 \\
>  \end{bmatrix}$ has eigen-vectors $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 &
>  1\end{bmatrix}^T$, $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}^T$ and
>   $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}^T$. What is $A^{11} \bar{x}$,
>   when $\bar{x}=\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^T$?

Now I think the key point is to realize

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^T=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^T+\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^T-\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^T$$

then we get

$$A^{11}\bar{x}= A^{11}\bar{x}_1+A^{11}\bar{x}_2-A^{11}\bar{x}_3$$

and since they are eigenvectors, we have $A\bar{x}=\lambda\bar{x}$ but here I mess up with things. I can calculate the eigenvalues from the determinant but I cannot understand which eigenvalue correspond to which eigenvector. According to my draft, the eigenvalues are $\lambda_h=1$, $\lambda_y=2$ and $\lambda_z=-1$ but how can I know which is $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$?

> **Draft**
>
> This is my work but it is not essential to understand the problem, it
>   probably show if I have misunderstood something.
>
> [image]

Comment: You have the eigenvectors $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$. Why not just calculate $A\cdot x_1$ etc. to see which eigenvalues they have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check easily that $A\bar x_1=2\cdot \bar x_1$:
$$\left(\begin{array}{rrr}1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0& 2 & 0 \\2 &1 &-1 \\ \end{array} \right) \; 
\left( \begin{array}{c}1 \\ 1\\ 1 \\ \end{array} \right)=\left( \begin{array}{c}2 \\ 2\\ 2 \\ \end{array} \right)=2\left( \begin{array}{c}1 \\ 1\\ 1 \\ \end{array} \right) $$
So, $\bar x_1$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue 2. In a similar way you'll find that $\left( \begin{array}{c}1 \\0\\ 1 \\ \end{array} \right)$ has eigenvalue $1$ and $\left( \begin{array}{c}0 \\0\\ 1 \\ \end{array} \right)$ has eigenvalue $-1.$